# IIS search the Newtonsoft reference on the framework directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, iis

I have a project in ASP.NET and add the Newtonsoft dll references, in local machine runs okey but when publish the site on the subdomain the IIS shows this error, but in the project directory has a Newtonwsoft.dll, I tryed add assembly reference in the web.config but it isn't work, I don't know why seach the resource in the next path.

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
> configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
> specific error details below and modify your configuration file
> appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built
> by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be
> loaded.
> Source File:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
> determine why the assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' could not be loaded.

Comment: how are you building it? most likely it is not getting the reference

Comment: I used NugetPackage, install the newtonsoft and add using Newtonsoft.Json, but also uninstall it and re install with PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json, and then I published with the VisualStudio wizard

Answer (score 0):

One possible general solution for these kind of problems might be to embed all dependencies by adding the nuget package "fody costura" to your project. This way all referenced C# dependencies should be compiled into your binary.

Comment: Ok, I just download but how I can to add dependecies? or only publish the site?

Comment: Uh, you dont compile a binary. Try if just publishing works, if not then i might consider deleting my answer...

Comment: I compile the app and upload the aspx and bin